# Convert timestamp to rfc 3339 in Python

Tags: python, timestamp, rfc3339

I am trying to convert the timestamp `1452454659` to its rfc3339 equivalent.

I am getting the output as:

`2016-01-11T01:07:39+05:30`

When I pass this to influxdb it returns a time of:

`2016-01-10T19:37:39Z`

while I actually want the time in influxdb to be:

`2016-01-11T01:07:39`

I have even tried to pass only `2016-01-11T01:07:39`, leaving out `+5:30`, but then it gives me no result.

What mistake am I making?

Comment: I do not want to use now() as my timestamp is already there as a string, and that is why i do not want to use "now()"

Comment: the added part: *"I am getting the output as 2016-01-11T01:07:39+05:30, when i pass this to influxdb it returns a time of: 2016-01-10T19:37:39Z from influxdb while i actually want the time in influxdb to be 2016-01-11T01:07:39."* is unrelated to your question *"convert timestamp to rfc 3339"*. Ask a new question about your issues with influxdb specifically.

Comment: All timestamps in InfluxDB are UTC. There are no time zones nor time zone support.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-4]+"Z"
2016-01-10T10:27:45.89Z
```

Answer (score 3):

if your timestamp is from utc format, the following example may help you : 
(just replace the variable 'd' with your own timestamp)

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print d.isoformat("T") + "Z"


--> 2016-01-10T09:33:33.865129Z
```

I based my answer on the following link : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a specialized python package for this:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/strict-rfc3339